# How to change last name as optional in Magento-2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

I want to change lastname as optional in customer address in Magento-2.

```
Vendor\magento\module-customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml
```

override into

```
mycompany\custommodule\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml
```

But i can't to override it.
If anyone knows please help me

Comment: There is not only front end validation , there is also server side validation done in magento 2 so you need check that side as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can override

> Vendor\magento\module-customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml

Create a Similar File Customer_form.xml in your custom module-

> mycompany\custommodule\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml

if you done it already then Kindly check your customer_form.xml file.

For More description please refer this link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html

Comment: sorry,already override it.removed required class. but it throw last name is required field error.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200459/change-lastname-as-optional-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

You can set **is_required** property `FALSE` for **lastname** attribute by this SQL query.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = '0' WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'lastname';
```

Then remove **required** class from lastname field by overriding this template file:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml
```