# change lastname as optional in Magento-2?

Tags: php, customer-account, magento-2.1.7

I want to **change last name as optional**. so

> Vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml

override into

> mycompany\custommodule\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml

1. Removed class required, required-entry
2. Changed in DB also

`UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'`

3. Also, null the lastname value in **customer-address-entity** table.
   I can create new customer without given lastname, but I can't proceed the customer address registration. **Lastname is required field** error throw in given customer address .(any other table contains last name field?)

If anyone knows please explain me...

Comment: Why have you asked multiple questions for the same. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200317/how-to-change-last-name-as-optional-in-magento-2

Comment: was this ever resolved? I have found several questions/answers, many yours, but none seem to work when applied to my 2.3 site